# Сортировка как в JavaScript, но в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

Имеется небольшой массив:

`[30, 1, 55, 5, 10, 20]`

Мне необходимо отсортировать этот массив как в JavaScript, но при помощи Python. То есть мне нужно нужно получить следующее:

`[1, 10, 20, 30, 5, 55]`

Как получить такой массив?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Можно не прописывать `lambda` целиком:

```
a = [30, 1, 55, 5, 10, 20]
sorted(a, key=str)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
a = [30, 1, 55, 5, 10, 20]
sorted(a, key=lambda x: str(x))
# Result: [1, 10, 20, 30, 5, 55]
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно также использовать `sort()` метод списка. Он изменяет список на котором происходит вызов метода (и возвращает `None`, чтобы избежать путаницы, в то время как `sorted` возвращает новый список не меняя оригинального списка):

```
>>> a = [30, 1, 55, 5, 10, 20]
>>> a.sort(key=str)
>>> a
[1, 10, 20, 30, 5, 55]
```

`key` - опциональный параметр, который указывает функцию, которая будет вызываться на каждом элементе списка перед сравнением. В нашем случае `key=str` - указывает на то, что элемент будет приведен к строке. Если его не указать, то метод отсортирует список по возрастанию чисел, по умолчанию, и получим массив: `[1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 55]`.

Обычно это менее удобно, чем метод `sorted`, но если вам не нужен оригинальный список (изначально несортированный - `[30, 1, 55, 5, 10, 20]`), то можно использовать этот метод, он более эффективен и прост в применении (на мой взгляд).